# Pass argument to VBScript from .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have some already written code as
    cscript //Nologo "%FILEPATH%\GetSys.vbs" >%PCKANRI%\sysinf.txt.

How do I add one argument to this and pass to `GetSys.vbs`. I want to pass `%PCKANRI%`'s value.

I tried -

```
 cscript //Nologo "%FILEPATH%\GetSys.vbs" >%PCKANRI%\sysinf.txt %PCKANRI%
```

and

```
cscript //Nologo "%FILEPATH%\GetSys.vbs"  %PCKANRI%  >%PCKANRI%\sysinf.txt
```

However, both don't work.

in `GetSys.vbs`
I have

```
Dim arg1
arg1 = args.Item(0)
MsgBox arg1
```

I get empty message nox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize `args` and deal with missing arguments:

```
type getsys.vbs
Dim args : Set args = WScript.Arguments
Dim arg1
If 1 <= args.Count Then
   arg1 = args(0)
Else
   arg1 = "No arguments!"
End If
WScript.Echo arg1

cscript getsys.vbs
No arguments!

cscript getsys.vbs argument
argument
```

And:

Putting the extra argument **after** the file spec (`...  >%PCKANRI%\sysinf.txt %PCKANRI%`) is wrong

Sorry, my mistake. Putting the argument at the end 'works'. Evidence:

```
cscript getsys.vbs argument > getsys.txt

type getsys.txt
argument

cscript getsys.vbs > getsys.txt option

type getsys.txt
option
```